# babel-eslint vs eslint-plugin-babel vs eslint-plugin-react?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint

What is the difference between the libraries?

- `babel-eslint` [[github.com/babel/babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint)]
- `eslint-plugin-babel` [[github.com/babel/eslint-plugin-babel](https://github.com/babel/eslint-plugin-babel)]
- `eslint-plugin-react` [[github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react)]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- `babel-eslint` is a parser that allows you to use ESLint with code that is supported by Babel (ES6+ features, flow types, etc.). ESLint on it's own only supports ES6, JSX and object rest/spread. Anything beyond that, requires `babel-eslint`.
- `eslint-plugin-babel` is a plugin that fixes/adds a few rules that work with ES7 and beyond features.
- `eslint-plugin-react` is a plugin that adds a bunch of rules specific to React applications.